# Context module not triggering Delta snapshot

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the Omega theme, and have the Delta and Context modules enabled. I created a Delta snapshot, and then created a Context to load that snapshot on the front page.

I created the context `Condition -> path -> <front>` and `Reaction -> Delta -> Select Custom theme settings template`. However, when I load the front page, the new snapshot doesn't load - it reverts back to the 'standard' Omega layout that I created.

I've tried deleting and recreating both context and snapshot, and clearing cache. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

ok...so I'm dumb. I guess this is for anyone else who is going too fast, like I was - I created the delta module for another theme. I didn't realize that the delta snapshots are per theme, which makes sense.